# copying paste solution to another computer mono.debugging.soft.disconnectexception

Tags: xamarin

Hi I have noticed that I develop a cross platform solution on my laptop and copy and paste it to my work computer or viceversa i get the error below and I cannot longer debug.

Is there something I need to do when a copy/move solution from one place to another?

I have rebuilt  deleted bin and obj still same problem

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Of course than that

Comment: We have 5 people working on the same xamarin project with git repository and we don't have that problem. So this is some issue with your environment

Comment: Fair enough  it's happening to my colleague too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been identified as a bug and should be fixed in an upcoming version of Xamarin for Visual Studio.

You can find the bugzilla bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56787

The release notes page also has a description of how to work around this issue here: https://releases.xamarin.com/common-issues-in-the-xamarin-15-2-2-release-being-tracked-by-the-xamarin-team/

> 1. Download the missing [Mono.Posix](https://dl.xamarin.com/uploads/bo4kicqj0a4/MonoPosix.zip) file and unzip the archive.
> 2. Right-click the Mono.Posix.dll file in Explorer and select Properties.
> 3. Check the Digital Signatures tab to ensure the file shows a valid Xamarin Inc. signature.
> 4. At the bottom of the General tab, if an Unblock checkbox appears, enable it and select OK. (This checkbox appears depending on how the file was downloaded.)
> 5. For Visual Studio 2017, copy the Mono.Posix.dll file into the “Xamarin.VisualStudio” extension directory. For example, for a default installation of the Enterprise edition, copy the file into:
>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio
> 6. For Visual Studio 2015, copy the file into the “Xamarin\Xamarin” extension directory:
>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\
> 7. Quit and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah that in a way is a relief I will try that